# How can I get a href,Image src,title from given html using DomDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Given Html -

```
  <div id="testid">
  <h1>Test Title</h1>
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="anker" id="artists-A"></li>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="www.test1.html" title="Test1">
            <span>
            <img src="https://www.test1.de/img/test1.jpg" alt="Test1" />
            <span>Test1</span>
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="www.test2.html" title="Test2">
            <span>
            <img src="https://www.test2.de/img/test2.jpg" alt="Test2" />
            <span>Test2</span>
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="www.test3.html" title="Test3">
            <span>
            <img src="https://www.test1.de/img/test3.jpg" alt="Test3" />
            <span>Test3</span>
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul> 
</div>
```

Need to get a href value,img src and span ie Title .
I am parsing this using domDocument but not getting exact result.

**Code:**

```
$doc = new DomDocument; 
$doc->validateOnParse = true; 
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url)); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//[@id="testid"]/ul/li');
```

Comment: show the code you are using  .. the result you get and the expected  result

Comment: $doc = new DomDocument;
    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    $doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 $nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@id="testid"]/ul/li');

Comment: youshould update your question and not add  the code in commen (is not easy read this code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). For now i am gathering `a`'s `href` and `img`'s `src`, you can add further more tags you want.

[**Try this code snippet here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecbfaf41ffd9c36fe37ebec557208eb298ce9202)

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//div[@id='testid']");//querying div with id="testid"
$results = $domXPath->query("//a|//img",$results->item(0));//querying resultant div for a and img
$data=array();
foreach($results as $result){
    if($result->tagName=="a")//checking for anchor tags
    {
        $data["a"][]=array(
            "href"=>$result->getAttribute("href"),
            "title"=>$result->getAttribute("title")
        );
    }
    elseif($result->tagName=="img")//checking for image tags
    {
        $data["img"][]=$result->getAttribute("src");
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: How can i get the result by testid

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library.

```html
<?php 

 require_once "SimpleHtmlDom.php";
 
 // put in file contentToParse.html your html code
 $htmlToParse = file_get_contents("contentToParse.html");
 
 $htmlObject = str_get_html($htmlToParse);
 
 $resultObject = array();
 
 
 foreach($htmlObject->find("#testid ul li a") as $singleLink)
 {
  var_dump($singleLink->href);
 }
        foreach($htmlObject->find("#testid ul li img") as $singleImage)
 {
  var_dump($singleImage->src);
 }
 foreach($htmlObject->find("#testid ul li span span") as $singleSpan)
 {
  var_dump($singleSpan->innertext);
 }
?>
```